# Can I turn a string into a block of code in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to turn a string into a block of code? I'm making an Ajax request to a website of mine that has an endpoint that returns some swift code as a string. I can get that code back as a string, but I can't run that code because it doesn't know that it is code.

Comment: Not a Swift programmer but this sounds like a bad idea for many reasons: 1- If the channel is compromised, an attacker can make your app execute arbitrary code trivially. 2- If this is an App Store app, Apple will reject it since they disallow downloading executable code. 3- You'd have to have your app compile the code which could be slow/impossible depending on the device. Ultimately, you should put that code in your app and have your server send you a message telling the app what code to run.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Swift is a compiled language, not interpreted like Ajax.

The Swift compiler runs on your Mac, not on the iOS device. (The same is true for Objective-C).

Plus, Apple's app store guidelines forbid delivering executable code to your apps, so even if you figured out a way to do it, your app would be rejected.

### Edit:

Note that with the advent of Swift playgrounds, it is possible to run the Swift compiler on an iPad. Recent high-end iPhones are probably also up to the job, but you'd have to figure out how to get it installed.

As stated above though, Apple's app store guidelines forbid you from delivering code to your apps at runtime.

Answer (score 18):

As others have pointed out, if you are creating an iOS app (especially for distribution on the app store), you can not do this.  However, if you are writing Swift code for an OS X machine AND you know that XCode is installed on the machine, you can run your Swift code string by running the command-line Swift compiler.  Something like this (with proper error checking, of course):

```
var str = "let str = \"Hello\"\nprintln(\"\\(str) world\")\n"    

let task = Process()

task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/swift"

let outpipe = Pipe()
let inpipe = Pipe()
inpipe.fileHandleForWriting.write(str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!)
task.standardInput = inpipe
task.standardOutput = outpipe
task.launch()
task.waitUntilExit()
task.standardInput = Pipe()

let data = outpipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()

let output = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
```

Again, this is probably not recommended in nearly all real-world cases, but is a way you can execute a String of Swift code, if you really need to.