# Is it possible to use a string variable in if condition in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm new to iOS development and wondering if I could pass a string variable inside if statement? Here's my pseudo code:

```
x = 1
func myFunc() -> String {
    myString = "x == 1"
    return myString 
}

if(myfunc()) {
   code i want to execute
}
```

I am currently getting the following error: "'String' is not convertible to 'Bool'"
Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: what are you trying to do in your if statement? Do you want to check if myFunc() is empty or not?

Comment: instead of writing   "if(x == 1)"    i am trying to use a variable so my if statement is "if(stringVaraible)" where stringVariable  =  "x ==1". Basically I am asking if it is possible to turn a string into normal code

Comment: no you can not. i have updated the answer

Comment: You can't do this, for the swift compiler and runtime  "x == 1" is just a string with no specific meaning. For this to work you would need some kind of interpreter that could take that string and convert it into an expression and then evaluate that expression.

Comment: you can use something like declare a empty string variable and assign the value you want to compare to that variable and then you can do the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a comparison operator for this.

```
if myString == myFunc() { 
// your code
}
```

If statement always wants a condition that can return a bool value. i.e. true and false.

In your above code, you are not providing sufficient data to if statement so that it can calculate whether the result iss true or false.

When you compare it like if `myString == myFunc()` , if statement will compare the string and return true if string matches else false.

if the string matches, it will execute the code that is within if conditions scope. Otherwise it will calculate the else condition.

**UPDATE1**:

I see you have updated the question, so you want to check if myFunc() is empty or not?

For that you can compare it with empty string.

```
if myFunc() == "" { 
// your code
}
```

**UPDATE2**:

**Question**: (asked in comment) instead of writing "if(x == 1)" i am trying to use a variable so my if statement is "if(stringVaraible)" where stringVariable = "x ==1". Basically I am asking if it is possible to turn a string into normal code

**Answer**: No, you can't do that. Swift is a compiled language, not interpreted like Ajax. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30058875/8374890

Comment: sorry, i didnt clearly state my question the first time. I updated it to so it makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

It's very specific and clear that you can't use String as boolean. The approach you can take is well known like..

```
if(myString == "x == 1") {
   code i want to execute
}
```

or

```
if(desiredString == myFunc()) {
   code i want to execute
 }
```