# Reading downloaded .swift file in bundle

Tags: swift

so, I'm a bit stuck on this as a concept/problem, and was wondering if any of you have encountered this as an issue/have a solution.

Let's simply say I built a character engine, like so: (I wouldn't do it this way, but this is just an example)

```
struct Character
var content: () -> String

init(_ content: @escaping () -> String) { 
    self.content = content
}
```

So now I can create a character like so

```
let heero = Character({"Heero"})
```

Great, awesome, cool. Now let's assume, for some reason, I have a `.swift` file on my server that contains a bunch of these characters, ex.

```
let relena = Character({"Relena"})
let wufei = Character({"Wufei"})
let quatre = Character({"Quatre"})
```

Is it possible for me to download the server `.swift` file, and have my app actually *use* it?

Comment: No, you can't do that. Swift is a compiled language, not interpreted like Ajax. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30058875/8374890

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Nope

Your app cannot download a swift file from a server, compile and execute it.

### However

Are you sure your `Character` struct initializer needs a closure as parameter? If you just need to pass a String then:

1. put the strings on the server into a JSON
2. fetch the JSON
3. read the JSON and create `Character(s)` from its content

### ---- Update ----

If you don't really need a closure in your Character struct you can follow this approach:

1. JSON
   Put all your strings into a JSON on the server

Here's how it looks on Playground

```
let data = """
{
"Hello I am Alex",
"Hello I am Bob",
"Hello I am Charlie"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

### Character

Next define your Character struct as follow

```
struct Character: Decodable {
    let content: String
}
```

### Decoding

Finally convert your JSON into an array of `Character(s)`

```
if let characters = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Character].self, from: data) {
    print(characters)
}
```

Comment: It definitely doesn't - the problem more comes in due to a whole chain of these closure parameter initializers - which I designed for better readability. The actual structure is something like `Script({Part({y("I'm saying something})})`

Comment: @MishaStone Ok, so you have a list of strings on the server (e.g. `"I'm saying something"`) and you want to build a Character for each one of these strings?

Comment: Yes, I think that's right. I guess the question really is, how do I decode/encode with a closure parameter in an initializer?

Comment: @MishaStone Got it, let me ask another question. Why do you want to put a closure into your Character struct? Why not simply a string property?

Comment: Well the actual struct for the `Script` class is a bunch of nested closure types - it's for readability more than anything. I didn't put that class in my question because it's just long lol